# Multiple domains on one Apache server(WAMP)

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, vhosts

I have got one IP address on my sv, and I want to set up two domains on one Apache Server with another DocumentRoot. Here is wat I got in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\mail"
    ServerName mail.A.pl
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName B.eu
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\B"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName A.pl
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Even when I try to load page: `http://www.A.pl` or `www.B.eu` or `B.eu` or `A.pl` it loads `mail.A.pl`.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDITED**

Here is new httpd-vhost, now it loads correct pages, but f.e. for A.pl  doesn't show any images, and on mail.A.pl doesn't want to send POST data:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\mail"
ServerAlias mail.A.pl
    ServerName mail.A.pl
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName B.eu
    ServerAlias *.B.eu
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\B"
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName A.pl
    ServerAlias A.pl
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT2**
Thank you both for help.

I just switched first VirtualHost with last and it mistery started working :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to have I think.

1) Uncomment the Virtual hosts line in Apache's config file so it includes `httpd-vhosts.conf`. On OSX that is:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

2) Put the necessary lines in your hosts file ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) ):

```
127.0.0.1 mail.A.pl
127.0.0.1 A.pl
127.0.0.1 B.pl
127.0.0.1 every.A.pl
127.0.0.1 subdomain.A.pl
127.0.0.1 needs-a-line.A.pl
```

The `ServerAlias` can go actually, you don't need that for subdomains, only for similar "main" domains.

Your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is fine.

Why the images and POSTs are not working I don't know. That doesn't have anything to do with this host file. Perhaps with another `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I have got uncommented it, also the domain is redirected to my server, I bought them, just changed real name to `A` and `B`

Comment: Something else on your server is probably wrong. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files for images expiration perhaps? I think you need to tell us more about your server's configuration and applications running on it. Maybe you just made a typo in a `<form>`'s location that POSTs? Or in the `<base href=""/>` of your app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to map `NameVirtualHost` to the IP address 127.0.0.1 for mapping multiple virtual host.

For example:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www'
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName myclient.local
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www\ClientsMyClient'
</VirtualHost>
```

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-setup-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/).

Comment: When I used `NameVirtualHost` with my IP of server, it was working, but other resources like images didn't load on any of those domains